# How to parse xml having only child nodes using SAX Parser

Tags: android

This is the xml data I get from the server. When i try to parse this using SAX Parser it gives exception in end document saying "junk data found". The reason for this is: tag1 is considered as startDocument and hence when first closing tag1 is found it considers endDocument is found and the rest data will be considered as junk. How can i continue parsing?
What is the solution for this?

```
<tag1 id ="browse">  
    <title id = "title">XML</title>
    <text>Text001<text>
    <text>Text002</text>
</tag1><tag1 id="status">  
    <title id = "title">XML Source</title>
    <text>Text003<text>
    <text>Text004</text>
</tag1>
```

PS: I can't modify the xml response as I get it from server. The response will be chunks of child nodes without an enclosing parent tag. The JAVA Applet I have uses a property called: "parser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/features/continue-after-fatal-error", Boolean.valueOf(true));" which works fine. But gives SAXNotFoundException in Android

Comment: I think your xml response in invalid.

Comment: can you please post sax parser code ?